# How to to change CSS double class properties through script

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, tabs

In JQuery UI, there are a lot of CSS double classes, for example for JQuery UI's tabs

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default  
{
    border: 3px solid #EEEEEE;      
    background: #ffffff url(BGDel.png) repeat-x; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: #ffffff; outline: none; 
}
```

The above works fine if it is in a CSS file.

I want to use javascript / Jquery to change one of property, like

```
$(".ui-widget-content .ui-state-active").css({"font-weight":"normal"} );
```

It doesn't work.  Could anyone help how to set or change the CSS double class properties through script? Thanks.

Comment: You can try `{"font-weight":"normal !important"}`. I am not sure if it will work but you can give it a try.

Comment: Do you see the style change when you examine the element in the DOM inspector?

Comment: Your element is `.ui-state-default`, why you are changing css for `.ui-state-active`?

Comment: @NOX He said that was just an example.

Comment: Do you understand that the jQuery code does NOT change the stylesheet. It just changes the styles of elements that match the CSS selector at the time that you execute that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".ui-widget-content .ui-state-active").css({"font-weight":"normal"} );
```

This line does not change the CSS class itself, it only selects an element matching this selector `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active`.

So please do an "Inspect element" for example in firebug or Google Developer Tools, find needed element, and see if you are using the right selector.

Since `.css()` function puts all given code into `style` attribute, it should override any class that is in CSS file, so i think, that you should try a different selector to match your element.

Answer (score 0):

There are two class apply on your element first is `.ui-widget-content` and second is `.ui-state-default`. 
in your example you set css to `.ui-widget-content` or `.ui-state-active`. but it is not correct because the a another css `.ui-state-default`  apply on that element.

so you need to use `!important` or also apply jquery code for`.ui-state-default` class

try -

> $(".ui-widget-content .ui-state-active").css('font-weight', 'normal!important' );

or

> $(".ui-state-default").css('font-weight','normal'); // for fire fox use css('font-weight', '400');

or

> $(".ui-widget-content .ui-state-active .ui-state-default").css('font-weight', 'normal');